# How to create a view with filters and pagination

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, development

I want to create a view with filters and pagination for Joomla 3.x, but I'm not sure about what I have to include and where.

For now, my model extends `JModelList` and I started  using the `getListQuery()` method to fetch the data:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class smartModelProducts extends JModelList{    

    protected function getListQuery(){
        // Initialize variables.
        $db    = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        // Create the base select statement.
        $query->select('*')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__smart_products'));

        return $query;
    }

}
```

My view.html.php looks like this:

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

class smartViewProducts extends JViewLegacy{

    function display($tpl=null){
        $app=JFactory::getApplication();
        $jinput = $app->input;
        $option = $jinput->get('option', null, null);
        $user=JFactory::getUser();

        // Get data from the model
        $this->state = $this->get('State');
        $this->items = $this->get('Items');
        $this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');

        parent::display($tpl);      
    }
}
```

What do I have to add to my model and my view? What is it that I have to include in my default.php so that both filters and pagination work?

Answer (score 8):

Follow the below steps:

## Filters:

1) Make sure to add all your filterable fields in your model constructor

```
public function __construct ($config = array())
{
    if (empty($config['filter_fields']))
    {
        $config['filter_fields'] = array(
           'id', 'a.id',
           'catid', 'a.catid',
           ....
           ....
        );
    }

    parent::__construct($config);
}
```

2) Populate your filter values in your model (products.php) for use like below

```
protected function populateState ($ordering = null, $direction = null)
{
    $search = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.search', 'filter_search');
    $this->setState('filter.search', $search);

    $authorId = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.author_id', 'filter_author_id');
    $this->setState('filter.author_id', $authorId);

    $published = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.published', 'filter_published', '');
    $this->setState('filter.published', $published);

    $categoryId = $this->getUserStateFromRequest($this->context . '.filter.category_id', 'filter_category_id');
    $this->setState('filter.category_id', $categoryId);

    // and so on .....
}
```

3) Add your filter xml file with required filter fields defined in `models/forms/filter_products.xml`

```
See administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/filter_articles.xml
```

4) Get and set filters in your `view.html.php`

```
$this->filterForm = $this->get('FilterForm');
$this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');
```

5) Display filters in list view `views/products/tmpl/default.php`

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default', array('view' => $this));?>
```

## Pagination:

1) Get pagination from model in your `view.html.php`

```
$this->pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
```

2) Display in your `views/products/tmpl/default.php`

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->getListFooter(); ?>
```

## Notes:

1. I suggest you to refer Joomla Articles (com_content) component for any Joomla MVC component development. It is the best resource/documentation available to-date.
2. The above codes are meant for admin component. For front-end component, most of the steps are more or less same but you need to tweak them as per your requirement.

Comment: I don't know how to create the xml for the filters. Could you please point me in the right direction? I thought it was possible to add them it in the model directly.

Comment: The code for displaying the filters and pagination must go within a form, right?

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: For pagination you don't need any xml file. JModelList defines required functions (getPagination), so it is readily available in your model.

Comment: What do I need the xml for? I want to know so that I can find out how to make one.

Comment: Your filter xml file should contain all fields for which you want to add filter. For example your component has categories and your list may have category filter.

Comment: If I have param on my menu item (catid) which I want to filter by, can I adjust like so? https://gist.github.com/AnrietteC/b56ead2e8f9aff16c05e246242304256